# How to disable AMD turbo boost in 22.04?

Tags: drivers, hardware, amd-graphics, cpu, amd-processor

so the problem is I cannot disable cpu boost. I have tried cpupower to change the governor or to lock cpu frequency on the specific numbers but idk when it needs to use these boost states it just sets everything to its default settings. I have tried the following from the forum:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost
```

but it no longer works though.
I also modified grub configuration in "/etc/default/grub" and inserted "processor.max_cstate=1 idle=nomwait" on "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" line and still nothing. [cpupower frequency-info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJI8C.png)